# expand rows for missing observations

Tags: r

I have a data set which was collected using 100 m transects. During data collection, a '0' was recorded if nothing was detected on the entire transect. If something was detected, a '1' was recorded along with the distance along the transect at 20 m intervals (20, 40, 60, 80, 100). For example;

```
Location Year Month Visit Air.Temp Transect Distance Present
Site1    2015 Feb   1     22.5      A       20       1
Site1    2015 Feb   1     22.5      A       40       1
Site1    2015 Feb   1     22.5      A       80       1
Site1    2015 Feb   1     23.0      B       20       1
Site1    2015 Feb   1     21.5      C       100      0
Site1    2015 Feb   2     24.0      A       80       1
```

I would like to expand my data set so that it includes a row for every 20 m interval which was searched, adding a '0' at the distances where nothing was recorded, and keeping the data associated with that particular transect (e.g. site, year, month, visit, temperature, etc.). For example, my desired output for the above would be;

```
Location Year Month Visit Air.temp Transect Distance Present
Site1    2015 Feb   1     22.5      A       20       1
Site1    2015 Feb   1     22.5      A       40       1
Site1    2015 Feb   1     22.5      A       60       0
Site1    2015 Feb   1     22.5      A       80       1
Site1    2015 Feb   1     22.5      A       100      0 
Site1    2015 Feb   1     23.0      B       20       1
Site1    2015 Feb   1     23.0      B       40       0
Site1    2015 Feb   1     23.0      B       60       0
Site1    2015 Feb   1     23.0      B       80       0
Site1    2015 Feb   1     23.0      B       100      0
Site1    2015 Feb   1     21.5      C       20       0
Site1    2015 Feb   1     21.5      C       40       0
Site1    2015 Feb   1     21.5      C       60       0
Site1    2015 Feb   1     21.5      C       80       0
Site1    2015 Feb   1     21.5      C       100      0
Site1    2015 Feb   2     24.0      A       20       0
Site1    2015 Feb   2     24.0      A       40       0
Site1    2015 Feb   2     24.0      A       60       0
Site1    2015 Feb   2     24.0      A       80       1
Site1    2015 Feb   2     24.0      A       100      0
```

I tried an expand.grid approach which has been suggested for similar questions, but in my case it throws a memory error because the data frame it tries to produce is too large (in reality, my data set has more columns of measured variables, and >1000 rows).

Any help is much appreciated! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1: Using `full_join` on `nest`ed data

```
skel <- data.frame(Distance = seq(20, 100, 20))

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by_at(vars(Location:Transect)) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(data = map(data, ~full_join(.x, skel, by = "Distance"))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    replace_na(list(Present = 0))
## A tibble: 20 x 8
#   Location  Year Month Visit Air.Temp Transect Distance Present
#   <fct>    <int> <fct> <int>    <dbl> <fct>       <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 Site1     2015 Feb       1     22.5 A              20       1
# 2 Site1     2015 Feb       1     22.5 A              40       1
# 3 Site1     2015 Feb       1     22.5 A              80       1
# 4 Site1     2015 Feb       1     22.5 A              60       0
# 5 Site1     2015 Feb       1     22.5 A             100       0
# 6 Site1     2015 Feb       1     23   B              20       1
# 7 Site1     2015 Feb       1     23   B              40       0
# 8 Site1     2015 Feb       1     23   B              60       0
# 9 Site1     2015 Feb       1     23   B              80       0
#10 Site1     2015 Feb       1     23   B             100       0
#11 Site1     2015 Feb       1     21.5 C             100       0
#12 Site1     2015 Feb       1     21.5 C              20       0
#13 Site1     2015 Feb       1     21.5 C              40       0
#14 Site1     2015 Feb       1     21.5 C              60       0
#15 Site1     2015 Feb       1     21.5 C              80       0
#16 Site1     2015 Feb       2     24   A              80       1
#17 Site1     2015 Feb       2     24   A              20       0
#18 Site1     2015 Feb       2     24   A              40       0
#19 Site1     2015 Feb       2     24   A              60       0
#20 Site1     2015 Feb       2     24   A             100       0
```

### Option 2: Using `tidyr::complete`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by_at(vars(Location:Transect)) %>%
    mutate(Distance = factor(Distance, levels = seq(20, 100, 20))) %>%
    complete(Distance, fill = list(Present = 0)) %>%
    mutate(Distance = as.integer(as.character(Distance)))
## A tibble: 20 x 8
## Groups:   Location, Year, Month, Visit, Air.Temp, Transect [4]
#   Location  Year Month Visit Air.Temp Transect Distance Present
#   <fct>    <int> <fct> <int>    <dbl> <fct>       <int>   <dbl>
# 1 Site1     2015 Feb       1     21.5 C              20       0
# 2 Site1     2015 Feb       1     21.5 C              40       0
# 3 Site1     2015 Feb       1     21.5 C              60       0
# 4 Site1     2015 Feb       1     21.5 C              80       0
# 5 Site1     2015 Feb       1     21.5 C             100       0
# 6 Site1     2015 Feb       1     22.5 A              20       1
# 7 Site1     2015 Feb       1     22.5 A              40       1
# 8 Site1     2015 Feb       1     22.5 A              60       0
# 9 Site1     2015 Feb       1     22.5 A              80       1
#10 Site1     2015 Feb       1     22.5 A             100       0
#11 Site1     2015 Feb       1     23   B              20       1
#12 Site1     2015 Feb       1     23   B              40       0
#13 Site1     2015 Feb       1     23   B              60       0
#14 Site1     2015 Feb       1     23   B              80       0
#15 Site1     2015 Feb       1     23   B             100       0
#16 Site1     2015 Feb       2     24   A              20       0
#17 Site1     2015 Feb       2     24   A              40       0
#18 Site1     2015 Feb       2     24   A              60       0
#19 Site1     2015 Feb       2     24   A              80       1
#20 Site1     2015 Feb       2     24   A             100       0
```

The downside of option 2 is that we need to convert `Distance` to a `factor` and then later back to an `integer` (or `numeric`).